# To delete data from one table relating other table

Tags: delete-row

How to delete row in one table if any data in other table is deleted.

Comment: Which programming language you are referring to?

Comment: Can you explain a little more ? In SQL? Ca you use triggers ?

Comment: Give us a chance! We aren't mind readers.

Comment: more importantly, which DMBS are you using?

Comment: @ThePower -- these questions are most fun because it's up to us to guess what the OP wants :)

Comment: @Matten - I'm no good at guessing games. I'm more of a quiz person than a charades enthusiast.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ON DELETE trigger. As you have not said which database system you use, it's up to you to google the right syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

If these tables have a reference constraint (such as an external key), you can use the `ON DELETE` trigger

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more detail.

Try searching for "cascading delete" and "referential integrity" in the documentation for whichever database you are using.